# vba how to loop through a list once and when finished tick up another item in a different array

Tags: excel, vba, selenium

I am trying to get the code to loop through the list once and then when it is finished with that list repeat the process again, but with the next item another item group.

in the code below there is a TerritoryGroupListRes(0). when it goes through all the items in AddingProductsToList. I want TerritoryGroupListRes(0) to go to the next one in that array

```
Dim a As Integer
    For a = 0 To AddingProductsToList.count - 1
        'filters
        Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:1")
        .FindElementByName("qbe0_1.20").Clear
        .FindElementByName("qbe0_1.20").SendKeys ("12/31/2040")
    
        'territory
        .FindElementByName("qbe0_1.46").Clear
        .FindElementByName("qbe0_1.46").SendKeys (TerritoryGroupListRes(0)) 
        'item grp 01 filter
        .FindElementByName("qbe0_1.36").Clear
        .FindElementByName("qbe0_1.36").SendKeys (AddingProductsToList(a))
        .FindElementById("hc_Find").Click
             
     'click on item after filters
     .FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='G0_1_R0']/td[1]/div/input").Click
     .FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='G0_1_R0']/td[1]/div/input").ClickDouble
    
    'expire the territory
        Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:2")
        .FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='G0_1_R1']/td[1]/div/input").Click
        .FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='G0_1_R1']/td[4]/div/input").Clear
        .FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='G0_1_R1']/td[4]/div/input").SendKeys(ExpireDate).Value
        .FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='G0_1_R1']/td[1]/div/input").ClickContext
        
        'for testing, will need to change to id=hc_OK"
        .FindElementById("hc_Cancel").Click
    Next a
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I typed that out I thought of nesting it:
as so

```
Dim a As Integer
    Dim b As Integer
    For a = 0 To TerritoryGroupListRes.count - 1
        For b = 0 To AddingProductsToList.count - 1
        
        'filters
        Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:1")
        .FindElementByName("qbe0_1.20").Clear
        .FindElementByName("qbe0_1.20").SendKeys ("12/31/2040")
    
        'territory
        .FindElementByName("qbe0_1.46").Clear
        .FindElementByName("qbe0_1.46").SendKeys (TerritoryGroupListRes(a))
        'item grp 01 filter
        .FindElementByName("qbe0_1.36").Clear
        .FindElementByName("qbe0_1.36").SendKeys (AddingProductsToList(b))
        .FindElementById("hc_Find").Click
             
     'click on item after filters
     .FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='G0_1_R0']/td[1]/div/input").Click
     .FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='G0_1_R0']/td[1]/div/input").ClickDouble
    
    'expire the territory
        Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:2")
        .FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='G0_1_R1']/td[1]/div/input").Click
        .FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='G0_1_R1']/td[4]/div/input").Clear
        .FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='G0_1_R1']/td[4]/div/input").SendKeys(ExpireDate).Value
        .FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='G0_1_R1']/td[1]/div/input").ClickContext
        
        'for testing, will need to change to id=hc_OK"
        .FindElementById("hc_Cancel").Click
      Next b
    Next a
```

If someone has a better solution or to do it better,  all ears.